# TypeError: users.map is not a function, trying to get the firestore document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having this error that says: TypeError: users.map is not a function
What seems to be the problem with my codes?

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const usersRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(id);
      const doc = await usersRef.get();
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log("No such document!");
      } else {
        setUsers(doc.data());
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
```

If I'll `console.log(doc.data())`, it does display the correct data. This error showed when I did this:

```
 {users &&
        users.map((index) => {
          <li>{index.firstName}</li>;
        })}
```

Update:
the doc.data() was an object

Comment: Is `doc.data()` an array?

Comment: Do you want to fetch all users or just one ?

Comment: @Andy I think it's an object

Comment: That's your answer then. Objects don't have a `map` a method.

Comment: @Andy right. I tried with `users.firstName` and it did show the data

Comment: It might make sense, if you're only returning one user based on an id, to call your state `user` rather than `users`.

Comment: can you show your doc.data output? please abstract Pii info if any

Comment: getData is an async function that must be awaited and since you are calling it inside another function that should also be declared as async. e.g: `**async** useEffect(() => {
    **await** getData();
  }, []);` Also, you need to check if users returns a truthy value which is not an array (that could potentially raise the TypeError exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `usersRef` is initialized like this:

```
const usersRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(id);
```

Since you include a `doc` call at the end there, the reference points to a single document in the `users` collection. So your `doc` is a single `DocumentSnapshot` and the `doc.data()` is the JSON for a single user's document, which explains why it doesn't have a `map` method (as the error message says).

---

If you want to load all users, you need to start with:

```
const usersRef = firestore.collection("users");
```

If you want to load a subset of all users, you can add a condition (`.where(...)`) to that.

---

If your `getData` loads the data you want: a single user, you'll probably want to pass it to your rendering code as an array of a single user with:

```
setUsers([doc.data()]); // Note the [] in there, those are new
```

---

If your code is only every supposed to be getting a single user, I'd recommend changing the names of your state hook and reference, and updating the rendering code to reflect that, as having `users` in that name implies there are multiple elements, and is just gonna lead to continued confusion.